# How to start unslider.js at certain index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

If I have three slides on my page how do I start on the second slide using unslider.js ([unslider](http://unslider.com/))? I've read through the docs but there doesn't seem to be any option for it. Should I try to manually edit the source?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this with moving to a specific slide index:

```
//  Move to a slide index, with optional callback
data.move(2, function() {});
//  data.move(0);
```

Slides start at a 0 index